# Java: read-only view of the union of two Maps?

Tags: java, collections

Is there an implementation of `java.util.Map` in a common library (Guava, commons-collections, etc.) that serves as a read-only view of a union of two backing maps? I.e., it would behave like `union` below, but without explicitly creating a new map instance, and reflecting future updates to the underlying maps:

```java
Map<K, V> a, b; // From somewhere
Map<K, V> union = new HashMap<>();
union.putAll(b);
union.putAll(a);
```

My searching hasn't turned up anything.

Comment: I guess it's impossible to create the such kind of view without merging source maps as, otherwise, it might be collision if map `a` has the same key as map `b` but with different value.

Comment: Short answer “no”. But it would be trivial to code it.

Comment: @AndriyKryvtsun - you could have one map take precedence over the other in cases like that, but, true, it does speak to difficulties in creating efficient implementations of `size()`, `keySet()`, `values()`, etc.

Comment: @Aron this specific behavior means there is no standard implementation for it. But you can implement `java.utils.Map` interface for it by yourself

Comment: @Bohemian “trivial” is subjective. I don’t see, how to implement an efficient `size()` or an `Iterator` for a union that does not require some storage of already encountered elements.

Comment: @Holger trivial: put OP’s code inside every RO method and return the delegated call. OP does not say it must have optimal efficiency or scale. If maps are small, execution time will probably be good enough. OP’s “requirement” of not creating a new map instance is an implementation detail that may not in fact be required.

Comment: @Bohemian I thought about it again and it’s actually doable. Still, not necessarily “trivial”.

Answer (score 1):

When you implement it yourself, you can extends `AbstractMap` whose only mandatory method to implement, is `entrySet()`. Implementing the entry set by extending `AbstractSet` requires an implementation for `iterator()` and `size()`. That’s the minimum required to implement a map.

Since a key may appear in both maps, we can not simply sum up the map’s sizes. So it has to be based on the same iteration logic as the `iterator()` implementation:

- take all entries from the first map
- take the entries from the second map whose key does not appear in the first one

Note that it’s possible that the resulting size exceeds the `int` value range. There’s no real solution to that. [`Collection.size()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#size()) specifies that `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will be returned when there are more elements, but I wouldn’t be surprised when this policy turns out to be unknown to many developers.

When implementing an iterator or similar facility handing out `Map.Entry` instances, we have to take care not to use the original map’s entries, as that would allow modifying the original map through the entry’s `setValue` method.

The iteration logic can be expressed concisely using the Stream API:

```java
public class MergedMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
    final Map<K,V> first, second;

    public MergedMap(Map<K, V> first, Map<K, V> second) {
        this.first = Objects.requireNonNull(first);
        this.second = Objects.requireNonNull(second);
    }

    // mandatory methods

    final Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet = new AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Map.Entry<K, V>> iterator() {
            return stream().iterator();
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            long size = stream().count();
            return size <= Integer.MAX_VALUE? (int)size: Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }

        @Override
        public Stream<Entry<K, V>> stream() {
            return Stream.concat(first.entrySet().stream(), secondStream())
            .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        }

        @Override
        public Stream<Entry<K, V>> parallelStream() {
            return stream().parallel();
        }

        @Override
        public Spliterator<Entry<K, V>> spliterator() {
            return stream().spliterator();
        }
    };

    Stream<Entry<K, V>> secondStream() {
        return second.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !first.containsKey(e.getKey()));
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return entrySet;
    }

    // optimizations

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return first.containsKey(key) || second.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return first.containsValue(value) ||
            secondStream().anyMatch(Predicate.isEqual(value));
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        V v = first.get(key);
        return v != null || first.containsKey(key)? v: second.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        V v = first.get(key);
        return v != null || first.containsKey(key)? v:
            second.getOrDefault(key, defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        first.forEach(action);
        second.forEach((k,v) -> { if(!first.containsKey(k)) action.accept(k, v); });
    }
}
```

Since it implements the iteration logic via the Stream API, the entry set also overrides the Stream related methods providing that Stream directly. This avoids inheriting implementations resorting to the iterator actually backed by a Stream.

Further, the map itself implements the common query methods for efficiency. The logic is similar, use the first map’s entry if present, the second map’s otherwise. Special attention is required to the possibility to have a key explicitly mapped to `null`, as some maps allow. The methods above use the optimistic approach, when a non-`null` value is present, only a single lookup is required.

Comment: Map a’s entries should override map b’s. Does your stream() impl of your entrySet() remove duplicate entries if maps share keys? BTW I wouldn’t have based my impl on streams - it’s not required and is not the simplest.

Comment: @Bohemian it does. All operations needing to filter the second map’s entries are using the method `secondStream()`, to have a single place for the filter logic. And it is the simplest approach not using additional storage. It is just a two-liner. I know, the simplest approach you suggested, is to just use the OP’s code and perform that every time an iterator is requested. Letting the expensiveness aside, it is only slightly shorter. As said in the other comment, I thought about it and realized that it is possible without additional storage. That’s why I posted that not-so-obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

I quite like Holger's answer, but here's a simpler approach that is easily understandable and debuggable. It delegates all read only methods to the union that is calculated on demand:

```
public class UnionMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> {
    private Map<K,V> a, b;

    public UnionMap(Map<K, V> a, Map<K, V> b) {
        this.a = Objects.requireNonNull(a);
        this.b = Objects.requireNonNull(b);
    }

    private Map<K,V> union() {
        Map<K, V> union = new HashMap<>(b);
        union.putAll(a);
        return union;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return union().entrySet();
    };

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return union().containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return union().containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return union().get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        return union().getOrDefault(key, defaultValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        union().forEach(action);
    }
}
```